# Vim editor: select word with Alt+Return

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I used a certain editor for many years and got used to selecting words with Alt+Return. I can't lose that habit and still try to do that in Vim too often, always without success.

So I try these:

```
noremap     <M-Return>  viw
noremap     <C-Return>  viw
```

You see, I am trying both, Alt+Return and Ctrl+Return. But neither works.

This works:

```
noremap     <C-M>   viw
```

I press Ctrl+m and the word is selected. But it comes with a strange side effect: Return/Enter alone also selects words! And I don't want that.

So it's a double question:

1) How can I make Alt+Enter select the current word (under cursor)?

2) Why does Return/Enter act like Ctrl+m?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 3):

The solution would depend on your terminal and how it's set up. Unix terminals generally send a *meta* character or sequence when you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press another key. There are two traditional ways of sending meta characters to terminal programs:

1. Take the ASCII value of the other key pressed (i.e. the one that's not <kbd>Alt</kbd>) and `OR` it with 128 (setting bit 7 high). This is discouraged these days because the resulting 8-bit character code isn't compatible with UTF-8 or even 8-bit encodings like Latin-1.
2. Send an escape character, ASCII 27, and then the ASCII code for the other key. This works well with a variety of encodings, but it can complicate the handling of cases where you actually meant to send an explicit escape character, e.g. when you hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> in Vim.

If your terminal is set to use #2, you might be tempted to do `noremap <Esc><CR> viw`. However, this will make Vim pause any time it receives an escape. To avoid this, you can `set` an `<A-CR>` *key code* and use that in the `map`; this makes it so that Vim can treat the sequence as different from an escape+character sequence (in particular, the sequence can have a timeout that's much shorter than the one used by other mappings; since terminals send the escape character and the following character almost simultaneously, this can guard against accidentally triggering a key code when you're not trying to).

The `set` command itself interprets strings like `<Esc>` literally (i.e. doesn't convert that into ASCII 27), so you have to wrap it in an `exec`:

```
exec "set <A-CR>=\<Esc>\<CR>"
```

After that, you can finally do a mapping:

```
noremap <A-CR> viw
```

You probably also want to set a very short `ttimeoutlen` so you don't accidentally trigger this new mapping with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>, e.g.

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
```

would make "normal" mappings wait a full 3 seconds between keys but key code mappings only a tenth of a second.

**References**:

1. `:h :set-termcap`
2. `:h :map-alt-keys`
3. `:h 'ttimeout'`

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal or put yourself in insert mode in vim and then press `<c-v>Return` and you will see why your `<C-M>` binding has that effect.

That should also explain to you why you can't bind `<C-Return>` or `<M-Return>` in console vim (you might be able to in gvim but I'm not sure).

Comment: Ok, Ctrl+m is the same as Enter. That part of the mystery is solved.

Comment: That solves both parts if you think about it. If <Enter> is <C-M> then what would <C-Enter> be? Or <M-Enter>? Like I said, gvim might be able to bind these because it has additional keypress/etc. detection capabilities (though whether this key falls into the set that gvim can handle but vim can't I'm not sure).

Comment: I don't use gvim, ever.

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible?

Comment: In console vim? I don't believe it is possible. I don't believe that is a generally representable key sequence. Current versions of xterm can represent it I believe but vim cannot use that representation format.

Comment: I think you will have to lose that habit or, maybe, use GVim instead of Vim.